# Select all cells inside the table

Tags: css

Is it possible to apply style to all td's inside the table having specified ID?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, via descendant selector

```
#table-id td { background:red }
```

HTML

```
<table id="table-id"><tr><td>Hi</td><td>, There</td></tr></table>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FjpBa/1/